# Javascript - remove duplicate objects from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, angularjs, object

I'm building an application which involves the creation of an array of objects, similar to this:

```
var foo = [{
'foo' : 'foo1' 
},
{
'foo' : 'foo2' 
},
{
'foo' : 'foo3' 
}];
```

there's then an HTML form where the user fills in the values for new objects. When the form is submitted the new values are pushed to the array. what I want is an if/else statement which checks if the new object already exists in the array. 
So something like:

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit',function(){
var newObject = {'foo' : input value goes here }
if (//Checks that newObject doesn't already exist in the array) {
    foo.push(newObject)
}
else {
//do nothing
}
});
```

It's also probably worth noting that I'm using Angular

Comment: Just use `Object` instead of `Array`.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: ECMAScript 6 Gives you the `.find()` method.  `if (foo.find(function(obj) { return obj.foo === newObject.foo; }) === undefined) { foo.push(newObject); }`

Comment: is [].find() any better than [].some() in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach:

You need:

1. Understand how to compare 2 objects.
2. Do it in cycle.

## How to compare 2 objects.

One of the ways is:

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

Note, that comparing ojbects this way is not good:

> Serializing objects merely to compare is terribly expensive and not
>   guaranteed to be reliable

As cookie monster mentioned in comments to this post. 
I just suggested it, to achieve what you want. You can find better variant. You can find some beautiful answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068834/2898694).

## How to do it in cycle :D

In your case it will be:

```
function checkIfObjectExists(array, newObject) {
    var i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        var object = array[i];
        if(JSON.stringify(object) === JSON.stringify(newObject)) 
        {
            return true;
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, I added function, so you can use it in your code.

Now add this to your code:

```
if (checkIfObjectExists(foo, newObject)) {
    // objects exists, do nothing
}
else {
    foo.push(newObject);
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2hn9X/10/)

Comment: Serializing objects merely to compare is terribly expensive and not guaranteed to be reliable. Also we don't know if all properties should match or just one. And using `for-in` on an Array is generally considered a bad practice. And finally you're creating an implicit global variable in your function.

Comment: I just suggested way to serialize objects and provided link to source, where he can find another ways. +. Didn't know about `for-in` — why it is so; where I can read about it? I edited my answer; is it correct now?

Comment: It's slower, it gives no absolute guarantees of order and if `Array.prototype` is extended, it'll hit those properties. So there are just too many strikes against it making it not worthwhile when there are no such issues when using a traditional `for` loop. But don't forget about `var` before `item`. That's where the implicit global is being created.

Comment: @cookiemonster, thanks for this explanation. Next time, I will use for (and will edit my answer now). Also, I edited problem with `item` variable.

Comment: @cookiemonster also removed `for-in` cycle and added `for` cycle + mentioned about serializing objects. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to loop through the foo-array and check for any duplicates.

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit',function(){
    var newObject = {'foo' : input value goes here }
    if (!isInArray(foo, newObject, 'foo')) {
        foo.push(newObject)
    }
});
function isInArray(arr, newObj, type) {
    var i, tempObj, result = false;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        tempObj = arr[i];
         if (tempObj[type] === newObj[type]) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's easier and faster if your array doesn't contain objects. Then you simply can make the if-clause to be:

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit',function(){
    var newString = "foo bar";
    if (foo.indexOf(newString) === -1) {
        foo.push(newString);
    }
});
```